# Linux won't boot after /bin/rm: not found error

Tags: linux, boot, shell, linux-mint

I tryed to install Mathematica on my Linux Mint.
I downloaded the .sh and made it executable with

```
chmod +x
```

Then I ran the .sh and it asked to overwrite /usr/local/Wolfram, which I accepted because the folder didn't exist. The installation aborted because it required admin permission. So I ran the .sh again, this time with sudo. Now the instalation aborted with the error "/bin/rm : not found". I tried one ls command on the shell and it also reported "not found". So I attempted to restart the shell, but it wouldn't open again. So I restarted the pc, but now Linux won't boot. How can I fix this? Thaks for the attention.

Comment: Can we see the `.sh` file? A poorly written script can wreak havoc e.g. when it doesn't catch some variable being empty. [See what Steam did few years ago](https://www.theregister.com/2015/01/17/scary_code_of_the_week_steam_cleans_linux_pcs/). You run the script with `sudo` and by the symptoms it looks maybe it removed everything; or a lot. Do you have a backup?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I can't reproduce the `.sh` file here because it has 4.13 GB. I don't have a backup, but luckily it was a recent linux installation. I sent a message to Mathematica's support, hope they have a helpful answer